# unable to restore table rows during orientation changes in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablelayout, android-orientation

I have called addRow() 3 times at onCreate so users will have 3 rows to start with. But they can add or remove rows as they wish. but when the screen rotates it only displays 3 rows. If I remove those 3 lines of function calling it does not display any rows upon rotation. I was able to restore all UI data except Table Rows. If you have 2 rows and you rotate then it automatically adds the 3rd row. if it is more than 3 it only shows the first three. I have given ids too. This is my first (kinda) original app and it's fully completed except for this issue.
ERROR - IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 3.
In this code below it does not crash, it simply does not display the rows. In my complete app, it does crash upon rotation but the error appears to be with "editTextCell" as in this case.
Below is the code as small as I could make without losing the context of this. I would reaaaally appreciate any help. I seriously do not want to lock this into portrait only.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var idNextCell = 1000
private var idNextRow = 0
private var idPlayerName = 2000
private var counter = 0
private var rowCounter = 0
private var colTotal = 0.0
private var removeTableRow: ArrayList<View> = ArrayList()
private val editTextPlayerNames: ArrayList<EditText> = ArrayList()
private var editTextCell: ArrayList<ArrayList<EditText>> = ArrayList()
private var colTotalList: ArrayList<Double> = arrayListOf()
private val colAverageList: ArrayList<Double> = arrayListOf()
private var scoreTable: TableLayout? = null
private var resultTable: TableLayout? = null
private var rowResult: TableRow? = null
private var noOfPlayers = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    noOfPlayers = 2
    addPlayerNames()

    scoreTable = findViewById(R.id.score_table)
    scoreTable?.isStretchAllColumns = true
    scoreTable?.isShrinkAllColumns = true

    resultTable = findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.table_result)
    resultTable?.isShrinkAllColumns = true
    resultTable?.isStretchAllColumns = true

    rowResult = TableRow(this)
    
    addRow()
    addRow()
    addRow()

    buttonAddRow.setOnClickListener {
        addRow()
    }
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener {
        if (rowCounter >= 1) {
            addAllColumns()
            displayResult()
        }
    }
    buttonDelRow.setOnClickListener {
        if (counter >= 1) {
            for (i in removeTableRow.asReversed()) {
                scoreTable?.removeView(i)
                removeTableRow.remove(i)
                counter--
                break
            }
            for (col in 0 until noOfPlayers) {
                for (row in 0 until rowCounter) {
                    if (row == counter) {
                        editTextCell[row][col].text = null
                    }
                }
            }
            rowCounter--
            addAllColumns()
            displayResult()
            if (rowCounter == 0) {
                for (i in 0 until noOfPlayers) {
                    rowResult!!.removeAllViews()
                    resultTable?.removeView(rowResult)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun addPlayerNames() {
    val playerNamesTable = findViewById<TableLayout>(R.id.table_player)
    playerNamesTable.isStretchAllColumns = true
    playerNamesTable.isStretchAllColumns = true

    val rowPlayerNames = TableRow(this)
    val emptyTextView = TextView(this)
    rowPlayerNames.addView(emptyTextView)

    for (col in 0 until noOfPlayers) {
        val playerName = EditText(this)
        playerName.id = idPlayerName
        idPlayerName++
        playerName.hint = "name"
        editTextPlayerNames.add(playerName)
        rowPlayerNames.addView(playerName)
    }
    playerNamesTable.addView(
        rowPlayerNames,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
}

private fun addRow() {
    for (row in 0 until 1) {
        editTextCell.add(rowCounter, ArrayList<EditText>())  // error appears at this line
        val nextRow = TableRow(this)
        nextRow.id = idNextRow
        idNextRow++
        removeTableRow.add(nextRow)
        val round = TextView(this)
        round.text = "R${++counter}"
        nextRow.addView(round)

        for (col in 0 until noOfPlayers) {
            val nextCell = EditText(this)
            nextCell.id = idNextCell
            idNextCell++
            nextCell.hint = "0"
            nextRow.addView(nextCell)
            editTextCell[rowCounter].add(nextCell)
        }
        scoreTable?.addView(
            nextRow,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        rowCounter++
    }
}

private fun addAllColumns() {
    colTotalList.clear()
    colAverageList.clear()
    // to add all column values
    for (col in 0 until noOfPlayers) {
        for (row in 0 until rowCounter) {
            if (editTextCell[row][col].text.isEmpty()) {
                colTotal += 0.0
            } else {
                colTotal += editTextCell[row][col].text.toString().toDouble()
            }
        }
        colTotalList.add(colTotal)
        colTotal = 0.0
    }
}

private fun displayResult() {
    rowResult!!.removeAllViews()
    resultTable?.removeView(rowResult)
    val result = TextView(this)
    result.text = "Total"
    rowResult?.addView(result)

    //to display  column total
    for (value in 0 until colTotalList.size) {
        val colTotalTV = TextView(this)
        if (colTotalList.sum() != 0.0) {
            colTotalTV.text = colTotalList[value].toLong().toString()
        }
        colTotalTV.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        rowResult?.addView(colTotalTV)
    }
    if (rowCounter >= 1) {
        resultTable?.addView(
            rowResult,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
    }
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    rowCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("rowCounter")
    val ctListSize = savedInstanceState.getInt("ctListSize")
    val avgListSize = savedInstanceState.getInt("avgListSize")
    val ctList = savedInstanceState.getDoubleArray("coltotalList")
    val avgList = savedInstanceState.getDoubleArray("averageList")

    if (ctList != null && avgList != null) {
        for (col in 0 until ctListSize) {
            colTotalList.add(col, ctList[col])
        }
        for (col in 0 until avgListSize) {
            colAverageList.add(col, avgList[col])
        }
    }
    if (rowCounter >= 1) {
        displayResult()
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putInt("ctListSize", colTotalList.size)
    outState.putInt("avgListSize", colAverageList.size)
    outState.putInt("rowCounter", rowCounter)
    outState.putDoubleArray("coltotalList", colTotalList.toDoubleArray())
    outState.putDoubleArray("averageList", colAverageList.toDoubleArray())
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

By default, when the screen is rotated your Activity is killed and restarted. To make sure no data is lost, you need to properly save and restore your data using the lifecycle methods. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

You might want to use SharedPreferences that saves the number of rows whenever user adds or removes them and extract them in onCreate() or onConfigurationChanged() method.

Comment: Have a read of this too, it outlines some options: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states This might be a good time to learn about ``ViewModel``s!